# why is there a difference between UTC time stamps in 2013 and 2008

Tags: matlab, utc

I am taking the difference of two UTC timestamps for two data sets.

1. 2008 dataset
2. 2013 dataset

when I take the difference in 2nd dataset, it gives me the difference in millisecs, but when I do the same in 1st dataset, it gives me the difference in seconds. What is the reason for this?

Sample data:

```
 1) [1.202497980000000e+09 - 1.202499025000000e+09]
 2) [1.360250174775000e+12 - 1.360250703765000e+12]
```

Comment: It would seem that the format of your data has changed between 2008 and 2013. Why not just multiply/divide one by 1000 and compare to the other?

Comment: Are you sure they are POSIX time stamps? POsIX time stamps should be something in the order of 7e+5!

Comment: @AndrewMao I want to know whether there is a change in format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matlab will not treat the data differently based on whether it is data from 2008 or 2013. Therefore the obvious suspect is the source. I am also quite sure that the UTC standard has not been changed from seconds to milliseconds.

This leaves two scenarios:

1. When this data was generated and stored in 2008 it was therfore likely done in a different way and than it is done now. This means one of them is not in the official format.
2. Alternately you may just be comparing two different things, perhaps there really was a difference of a second between the first two timestamps and a difference of a millisecond between the last two.